# How to enable or disable plugins from manifest file?

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, installation, xml, manifest

I have written a component and it installs fine except that the plugins are all installing as enabled.

What I want to do is enable some and disable others.  Here is what I have tried:

```
<plugins folder="plugins">
    <plugin name="com_softmedia" group="xmap" enable="true" />
    <plugin name="softmedia" group="search" enable="true" />
    <plugin name="softmedia" group="finder" enable="true" />
    <plugin name="paypal" group="softmedia" enable="false" />
    <plugin name="skrill" group="softmedia" enable="false" />
    <plugin name="2checkout" group="softmedia" enable="false" />
    <plugin name="stripe" group="softmedia" enable="false" />
    <plugin name="quickpay" group="softmedia" enable="false" />
    <plugin name="addthis" group="softmedia" enable="false" />
    <plugin name="joomla" group="softmedia" enable="true" />
    <plugin name="liketodownload" group="softmedia" enable="false" />
    <plugin name="euvat" group="softmedia" enable="false" />
    <plugin name="dlejproducts_update_helper" group="system" enable="true" />
</plugins>
```

I have seen this done as "enable and activate", but neither of these will work for me.

Comment: In the Stack Exchange Network, we never "resolve" a question by editing the question.  If/When you self-solve, the appropriate way to resolve the page is to post an answer to your own question.  Please rollback your edit -- you'll get a badge for doing this :) -- then post your resolving advice as answer with the intent to educate future researchers.  If there are any supporting documentations that you can link to, please add that to your answer.  Please always be generous.

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work properly you would use enable="true" to enable the plugin and disable="true" to disable the plugin.